# Как проверить является ли неориентированный граф двудольным

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Можете дать алгоритм , который определит можно ли перекрасить неориентированный граф в 2 цвета , или же просто алгоритм , который проверяет является ли неориентированный граф 2-цветым(двудольным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть простой алгоритм. Используете любой алгоритм (поиск в ширину или глубину), что бы пройти по всем вершинам. Каждую вершину при посещении разукрашиваете в белый или черный цвет (можно хранить отдельно массив с разукрашенными вершинами.

Правило раскраски - две соседние вершины должны быть разного цвета. То есть, если текущая белая, то соединенные с ней - черные. Если все вершины разукрасились - ура, наш граф двудольный. Если в процессе разукраски натолкнулись на уже покрашенную вершину и цвет совпал, ок, продолжаем. Если не совпал - нашли проблемное место, грав не двудольный.

Более строгое математическое определение - все циклы в таком графе - четные. (теорема Кенига).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389945 нашел в интернете такой алгоритм, является  ли он ответом?

Comment: очень похоже на правду, как минимум анимация внизу

Comment: Ну зачем вы ищете готовые ответы? Напишите свой, потратьте время — это будет отличное вложение в самого себя... А то получается [гуглопрограммизм](https://habr.com/ru/post/521104/)...